# Insert closing curly brace '}' when pressing enter in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

When I put an opening curly brace `{` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to make a new line, WebStorm automatically places a closing curly brace `}`. How can I stop this? I cannot find it in WebStorm's preferences:

`Settings -> Code Style -> JavaScript -> Wrappings and Braces` shows nothing relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

`Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys | Enter | Insert pair '}'`

In general:

`Settings | Editor | General | Smart Keys | Insert pair brackets (), [], {}, <>`

That's how you do it in [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/settings-smart-keys.html) and [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/settings-smart-keys.html).

Comment: Yes! More precisely `settings -> editor -> smart keys -> Enter -> insert pair '}'` (There are two similar options. The second one works.) Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm using angularjs plugin http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6971 but when I open the braces {{ in html file it doesn't add closing braces as stated in the log, I checked smart keys -> Enter -> insert pair '}' it is already checked, please advice

Comment: I was about to throw my mac in a window! Thank you, you saved my mind from insanity!